# Getting .py file to save list to .txt file without overwriting it

Tags: python, python-3.x

[Beginner trying to learn python3, please explain like I'm 5]

So I wrote this code:

```
x = [2, 3, 4, 5] # The List
print(f"The list is {x}.") # Displays default list
user = int(input("A number to add to list: ")) # Asks user to add a number
x.append(user) # Appends user's number into list

file = open("ListElements.txt", "w")  # Opens a file for writing and puts it in the file variable
file.write(f"{x}") # Writes the entire list + the appended element into new file
file.close()  # Closes the file

print("The List is now: ") # Print out the string
print(open('ListElements.txt', "r").read()) # Prints out the contents of the ListElements.py
```

It's supposed to take a list of numbers and ask the user to add a number into the list. Then it saves that new list as text into the ListElements.txt file. It does that fine. But if I run the program again, it overwrites the ListElements.txt file instead of adding to its content. How can I get it to save it as a new line and not overwrite it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a method called `append` using `a` that will enable you to add to the end of the file. Make sure the file exists first.

```py
x = [2, 3, 4, 5] # The List
print(f"The list is {x}.") # Displays default list
user = int(input("A number to add to list: ")) # Asks user to add a number
x.append(user) # Appends user's number into list

for num in x:
    file = open("ListElements.txt", "a")  # Opens a file for writing and puts it in the file variable
    file.write(f"{num}\n") # Writes the entire list + the appended element into new file
    file.close()  # Closes the file

print("The List is now: ") # Print out the string

new_x = []
for line in open('ListElements.txt', "r").readlines():
    new_x.append(int(line))
print(new_x) # Prints out the contents of the ListElements.py
```

Make sure to insert a new line after each thing you write otherwise it will just be like `12345` instead of

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Comment: How do I insert a new line to it?

Comment: @CustardJesus using `\n` as shown in the example after `{x}`

Comment: I see, thank you. One last question; the output shows up as: 

The List is now:
[2, 3, 4, 5, 90]
[2, 3, 4, 5, 9090]

Is there any way to get it to input 90 and 9090 into the same list instead of creating a new one?

Comment: If I have solved your question mark it as correct @CustardJesus

Comment: I did! Thank you very much.